# python class behaves like dictionary-or-list-data-like

Tags: python, list, class, dictionary

In python3 console, input those:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
>>> type(sys.version_info)  # this is class type
<class 'sys.version_info'>
>>> sys.version_info[0:2]  # ?? But it acts like a list-data-like
(3, 4)
```

My questions are:

1. How can a class act like dictionary-or-list-data-like?
2. May give an example to construct a class like this?
3. Is there some documentation about
   this?

Comment: Note, this isn't behaving like a dictionary ... It's behaving a lot more like a sequence with named members.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. It's my mistake.@mgilson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python contains several methods for [emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) such as dictionaries and lists.

In particular, consider the following class:

```
 class MyDict(object):
     def __getitem__(self, key):
          # Called for getting obj[key]

     def __setitem__(self, key, value):
          # Called for setting obj[key] = value
```

If you write

```
obj = MyDict()
```

Then

```
obj[3]
```

will call the first method, and

```
obj[3] = 'foo'
```

will call the second method.

If you further want to support

```
len(obj)
```

then you just need to add the method

```
def __len__(self):
    # Return here the logical length
```

---

Here is an example of a (very inefficient) dictionary implemented by a list

```
class MyDict(object):
    def __init__(self, seq=None):
        self._vals = list(seq) if seq is not None else []

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return [v[1] for v in self._vals if v[0] == key][0]

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        self._vals = [v for v in self._vals if v[0] != key]
        self._vals.append((key, val))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._vals)
```

You can use it pretty much like a regular `dict`:

```
obj = MyDict()
obj[2] = 'b'
>>> obj[2]
'b'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy ... All you need to do is define a `__getitem__` method that handles slicing or integer/string lookup.  You can do pretty much whatever you want...

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, bar, baz):
        self.bar = bar
        self.baz = baz
    def __getitem__(self, ix):
        return (self.bar, self.baz).__getitem__(ix)
```

Here's a cheat sheet of what will be passed to `__getitem__` as `ix` in the following situations:

```
f[1]  # f.__getitem__(1)
f[1:]  # f.__getitem__(slice(1, None, None))
f[1:, 2]  # f.__getitem__( (slice(1, None, None), 2) )
f[1, 2]  # f.__getitem__( (1, 2) )
f[(1, 2)]  # f.__getitem__( (1, 2) )
```

The trick (which can be slightly non-trivial) is simply writing `__getitem__` so that it looks at the type of the object that was passed and then does the right thing.  For my answer, I cheated by creating a `tuple` in my `__getitem__` and then I called `__getitem__` on the tuple (since it already does the right thing in all of the cases that I wanted to support)

Here's some example usage:

```
>>> f = Foo(1, 2)
>>> f[1]
2
>>> f[0]
1
>>> f[:]
(1, 2)
```

note that you don't *typically* need to even do this yourself.  You can create a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to do the job for you:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Foo = namedtuple('Foo', 'bar, baz')
```

And usage is pretty much the same:

```
>>> f = Foo(1, 2)
>>> f[1]
2
>>> f[0]
1
>>> f[:]
(1, 2)
```

The main difference here is that our namedtuple is immutable.  Once created, we can't change it's members.

Answer (score 0):

i think in python like ECMAScript (aka javascript) class is a dictionary or **associative array**([associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)). since you can add a property or method to your class at runtime.([see](http://slides.com/alirezaafzalaghaei/introduction-to-javascript#/7/3))

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
a = A()
a.y=5
print a.y # 5
```

if you want write a class like that you can use `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods:

```
class A(object):
    class B(object):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.vals = (x, y)
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.vals[key]
        def __setitem__(self, key, val):
            self.vals[key] = val
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.__vals)
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.b = self.B(x,y)



a = A('foo','baz')

print type(a.b) # __main__.b     __main__ because we run script straightly
print a.b[:]    # ('foo', 'baz')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same behaviour by overriding **getitem**() and **setitem**() in your class.

```
    class Example:
        def __getitem__(self, index):
            return index ** 2

    >>> X = Example()
    >>> X[2]                                
    >>> 4
```

You can override **setitem**() too in your class for achieving the setter kind of thing.